# Can FFmpeg create a gradient box with colors sampled from the box edges?

Tags: ffmpeg

As shown in these [video screen captures](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/22291118/ASL_Bible__1_.jpg), I would like to **replace** the text in the upper left of the videos to another language.

What I am thinking is first to create a **gradient box** with colors that are **automatically sampled** along the edges of the box. Then it would be easy to [`drawtext`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) the replacement text. For each [video file](https://www.jw.org/finder?wtlocale=ASL&pub=nwt), the background gradient doesn't change, so it can be sampled only once for each file.

Is this possible in FFmpeg? Other ideas on how to achieve the text replacement is also welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found an answer to my question: **FFmpeg [delogo filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#delogo)**

`delogo` options I used for the videos in the question is: (for testing you can set `show=1`)

`delogo=x=85:y=47:w=300:h=40:show=0`

Sample `ffmpeg`/`ffplay` `-vf` options for encoding, `delogo` + `drawtext` filters:

```
-vf "delogo=x=85:y=47:w=300:h=40:show=0,drawtext=text='SampleText':fontfile="${FONTFILE}":fontcolor=white:fontsize=34:x=93:y=54:alpha=0.9"
```

`delogo` is pretty neat, I wonder how they did this. Quite fast too.